# Mint/Cinnamon: cannot add keyboard layout anymore

Tags: keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I'm using Cinnamon 5.0.7 and try to install an additional keyboard layout (I have some defined already), which worked fine some time ago.

Now adding is disabled -- the <kbd>+</kbd> button is greyed-out. After some digging, I found a trace back from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-keyboard`, but I don't know what to make of it.

Any suggestions what to try next?

Comment: "SOLVED" in title is [not needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310). [Accept the best answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/355310) and this will formally mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of four layout definitions. I was trying to add the fifth. Removing one enabled me to define a new one.

Comment: For your information, the limit is in Cinnamon, not Linux desktops in general. I currently have five keyboard layouts in KDE, each with a shortcut to that language and a fast-switcher between English and my national language.